# When is the square root differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, roots

Let $f$ be a non negative differentiable function (defined on $\mathbb R$) and $g(x)=\sqrt{f(x)}$. Can you characterise the points $x_0$ where $g$ is differentiable at $x_0$?

It is clear that when $f(x_0)\neq0$ then $g$ is differentiable at $x_0$ (by chain rule). So the real question is, what happens when $f(x_0)=0$? For such a point it is easy to see that if $g$ is differentiable at $x_0$ then necessarily $f'(x_0)=0$. But the converse is not true as the example $f(x)=x^2$ shows (at $x_0=0$).

So for the points $x_0$ such that $f(x_0)=0$ under what conditions on $f$ is $g$ differentiable at $x_0$? I suspect that the answer is: $g$ is differentiable at $x_0$ iff $f''(x_0)=0$, but I cannot give a proof. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: How is $f(x)=x$ a counterexample to the converse? $f'(0)$ is not zero!

Comment: Do you want the zeros to be isolated for each other?

Comment: @TonyK Sorry, my mistake. Corrected.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro No, you don't have any additional information on $f$. Just that it is non negative and differentiable. But as I said you can just investigate the case where $f(x_0)=0$ since the other case is trivial.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! <> Haven't tried to write details, but offhand I'd try to characterize in terms of the largest real $\alpha$ such that, in some neighborhood of $x_0$, $$f(x) = |x - x_{0}|^{\alpha} \phi(x)$$for some continuous function $\phi$....

Comment: If $g(x)$ is twice-differentiable at $x_0$, we can conclude that 
$$
f(0) = f'(0) = f''(0) = f'''(0) = 0.
$$

Comment: I suspect that with Darboux's theorem, we can show that if $g$ is differentiable at $x_0$, then $g'(x)$ must be continuous at $x_0$

Comment: Before you study whether a function has a derivative at a point or not, it maybe good to specify the domain, then find the right and left limits around the point to test if the limit exists. If no limit exists, then you can't have a derivative. (at least I guess so....last time I used this was 40+ years ago).

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang That seems a good idea.

Comment: $g$ cannot have a non-zero derivative at $x_0$, as $g(x)$ would then be negative for some $x$ near $x_0$.

Comment: In the example above $f(x) = x^2\implies g(x) = \sqrt{x^2} =  |x|$

Answer (score 2):

According to the Peano-Taylor theorem, if $f$ is twice differentiable at $a$ then

$$f(a+x)=f(a)+xf'(a)+\tfrac12x^2f''(a)+x^2h(x)$$

where $h$ is some function continuous at $h(0)=0$. So here's one direction of a proof:

$$f(a)=f'(a)=f''(a)=0$$
$$f(a+x)=x^2h(x)$$
$$g(a+x)=|x|\sqrt{h(x)}$$
$$g'(a)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{g(a+x)-g(a)}{x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{|x|}{x}\sqrt{h(x)}=0$$

---

For the other direction, suppose $g(a)=g'(a)=0$:

$$f(x)=g(x)^2$$
$$f'(x)=2g(x)g'(x)$$
$$f''(a)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f'(a+x)-f'(a)}{x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{2g(a+x)g'(a+x)}{x}$$
$$=2\lim_{x\to0}\frac{g(a+x)-g(a)}{x}g'(a+x)=0$$

But this is assuming that $g'$ is defined and bounded in a neighbourhood of $a$. So here's a counter-example (let $x\geq0$ to simplify the notation, defining $g(-x)=g(x)$):

$$g(x)=x^{3/2}\sin^2x^{-1}$$
$$g(0)=g'(0)=0$$
$$f(x)=x^3\sin^4x^{-1}$$
$$f'(x)=3x^2\sin^4x^{-1}-4x\sin^3x^{-1}\cos x^{-1}$$
$$f''(0)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f'(x)-f'(0)}{x}=\lim_{x\to0}\Big(3x\sin^4x^{-1}-4\sin^3x^{-1}\cos x^{-1}\Big)$$

This limit doesn't exist; $4\sin^3x^{-1}\cos x^{-1}$ oscillates between $\pm3\sqrt3/4$.

---

Instead of referring to the ordinary second derivative, we can refer to the second Peano derivative, i.e. the coefficients of the best-approximating quadratic polynomial. The higher-order Peano derivatives of $f$ at $a$ are defined by

$$f(a+x)=\sum_{k=0}^n\tfrac{1}{k!}c_kx^k+x^nh(x),\qquad\lim_{x\to0}h(x)=0$$

It is true that the quadratic polynomial for $f$ at $a$ is $0$ if and only if the linear polynomial for $g$ at $a$ is $0$. Thus the condition you want is not $f''(a)=0$ but

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(a+x)}{x^2}=0.$$